# Problem about `evil-visual-state` and advising `read-key-sequence` with `call-process`

Tags: evil, process, advice

In Evil mode, after I enter `visual-state`, I can use `f` to expand the selection by jumping to a character. Now if I've pressed `f` after entering `visual-state`, Emacs asks me to input a character to jump to, which I think is implemented using `read-key-sequence`. What I want to do is to call some external process before I enter the character, so I advise the `read-key-sequence` function(below is a simplified version):

```
(defun foo (orig-func &rest args)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (call-process "ls" nil t))
  (apply orig-func args))

(advice-add 'read-key-sequence :around 'foo)
```

Now I enter the `visual-state`, press `f`, enter the character, jump to it, and nothing is shown selected, i.e., the region is not active.

However, if I just change the parameter of `call-process` by setting the fourth argument(`destination`) to be `nil`, i.e., using the following version of `foo`:

```
(defun foo (orig-func &rest args)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (call-process "ls"))
  (apply orig-func args))
```

Everything works fine, exactly like without adding advice to `read-key-sequence`.

My question is, is there something I did wrong, or something of `call-process` and Evil implementation will magically change the state of the region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a very simple question...Setting the fourth argument of `call-process`, i.e. `destination`, to `t` will insert the output into the buffer, which sets the variable `deactivate-mark` to `t`. Therefore, the mark is deactivated afterwards. The solution is to bind `deactivate-mark` to `nil` before the `call-process`:

```
(defun foo (orig-func &rest args)
  (let (deactivate-mark)
    (with-temp-buffer
      (call-process "ls" nil t)))
  (apply orig-func args))
```